# Mvc List Multiple Views Nested in Viewmodal

Tags: list, model-view-controller, view, nested, viewmodel

Hello guys can u help me to figure it out how to list nested viewmodels on single view

**Here is my viewmodel with nested 4 view that contains 4 different table data. As you can see below the "KentselDonusumViewModel" is the main viewmodel**

```
public class KentselDonusumViewModel
    {
       public IList<agaclarViewModal> agaclarViewModal { get; set; }
        public IList<fotografViewModal> fotografViewModal { get; set; }
        public parselViewModal parselViewModal { get; set; }
        public MahalleViewModal MahalleViewModal { get; set; }

    }
    public class agaclarViewModal
    {
        public int agac_id { get; set; }
        public string agac_turu { get; set; }
        public string yas_araligi { get; set; }
        public int fiyat { get; set; }
        public int parsel_id { get; set; }
        public virtual parselViewModal parsel { get; set; }
    }
    public class fotografViewModal
    {
        public int fotograf_id { get; set; }
        public string fotograf_adi { get; set; }
        public string fotograf_url { get; set; }
        public int parsel_id { get; set; }
        public virtual parselViewModal parsel { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class parselViewModal
    {
        public int parsel_id { get; set; }
        public int mahalle_id { get; set; }
        public int ada_no { get; set; }
        public int parsel_no { get; set; }
        public int parsel_alani { get; set; }
        public int kaks { get; set; }
        public int insaat_alani { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<agaclarViewModal> agac { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<fotografViewModal> fotograf { get; set; }
        public virtual MahalleViewModal MahalleViewModal { get; set; }

    }
    public partial class MahalleViewModal
    {
        public int mahalle_id { get; set; }
        public string mahalle_adi { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<parselViewModal> parsel { get; set; }
    }
```

**And there is my Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Listele()
    {
        var parselModal = (from p in db.parsel select new parselViewModal {
                                                        ada_no=p.ada_no,
                                                        mahalle_id=p.mahalle_id,
                                                        insaat_alani=p.insaat_alani,
                                                        parsel_alani=p.parsel_alani,
                                                        kaks=p.kaks,
                                                        parsel_id=p.parsel_id,
                                                        parsel_no=p.parsel_no
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        var mahalleModal = (from m in db.mahalle
                           select new MahalleViewModal
                           {
                             mahalle_id=m.mahalle_id,
                             mahalle_adi=m.mahalle_adi                                  
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

        var viewModal = new KentselDonusumViewModel
        {
            parselViewModal=parselModal,
            MahalleViewModal=mahalleModal,              
            agaclarViewModal = new List<agaclarViewModal>(),
            fotografViewModal=new List<fotografViewModal>()

        };
        return View(viewModal);
```

**its looks ok here but i dont know how to use this guys into View**

Can you help? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it easily,try something like this below codesnippets in your view

```
@for (int i = 1; i < Model.agaclarViewModal.Count; i++)
{
 <label class="control-label font-weight     none">@Model.agaclarViewModal[i].yas_araligi</label> <br />
}
```

Let me know, is this helpful for you....

Comment: Thanks for answer but i dont understand what do you mean by "DefineMBPureMixModel"

In fact my main problem is Listing <List> and single objects into a single view.

I mean i can use view page as:

foreach (var item in Modal)
{
item.id ...
}

But also i have single objects from another view and i want it to be shown in the same page like Html.Display(x=>x.somedata>

Hope i could explain myself

Comment: Oops..It was my model name..ohk..if your model has List<particular model>.you can use foreach and for having single variable with same model you can use Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.somedata)..try with this you will get the solution

Comment: Hi i'll try it asap